# Como acessar itens filhos num BoundField de uma GridView no Asp.Net Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, gridview

Eu sei que no meio de uma `GridView`, é possível ler um item imediato com a tag `BoundField`:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MeuItem" HeaderText="Meu item" />
```

Mas eu recebo um erro ao tentar fazer isso:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MeuItem.SubItem" HeaderText="Meu sub item" />
```

O erro lançado descreve-se:

> A field or property with the name 'MeuItem.SubItem' was not found on the selected data source.

Eu já chequei duas vezes se escrevi o nome corretamente e se precisar checo de novo.
Mas creio que não seja esse o problema.
Qual o melhor meio para atingir meu objetivo?

Comment: Que fonte de dados você colocou no `GridView`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez `List<MeuItem>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

Se a ideia for: um MenuItem possui suas propriedades e outro item (SubItem) do tipo MenuItem de modo a formar um encadeamento ou auto referência:

```
public class MenuItem { 
string Nome { get; set; }
MenuItem SubItem { get; set; }
}
```

Você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras, a primeira é acessar a propriedade do objeto filho via cast. A segunda é no momento da query.

**Modo 1**

Atribuindo o datasource ao gridview:

```
var MenuItens = contexto.MenuItem;
GridView1.DataSource = MenuItens.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Dentro do GridView defina campo personalizado, para acessar a propriedade nome:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span>string.Format("{0}", ((MenuItem)Eval("SubItem")).Nome)</span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Modo 2**

Monte seu data source do jeito que você precisa diretamente na query:

```
var MenuItens = contexto.MenuItem.Select(m => new
{ 
    Nome = m.Nome,
    SubItem = m.SubItem.Nome
});
GridView1.DataSource = MenuItens.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

No GridView basta acessar da seguinte forma:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SubItem" HeaderText="SubItem" />
```

Espero que dê para entender. Boa Sorte.

Comment: Acho que tem alguns erros no código, mas deu pra entender. Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback André.